# Can circular references cause errors in AutoHotKey?

Tags: debugging, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I wrote my first AutoHotKey script, but there seems to be an error in this section:

```
^;::Send ^z ; Undo
^q::Send ^x ; Cut
^j::Send ^c ; Copy
^k::Send ^v ; Paste
^x::Send ^+v ; Paste without formatting
```

I cannot get Cut to work (the 2nd line).

**What is the problem?**

If I comment out the 5th line, then Cut will work. However, I've never gotten them both to work at one time. Is the 1st line with the semi-colon (;) causing trouble?

Comment: It's always good to have a `$` before the hotkey to prevent repeated looping. Usually, it warns you that 'X number of keypresses have occurred in the last x seconds' but it seems in your instance it did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was indeed caused by hotkeys triggering other hotkeys, and it can be fixed with the `$` modifier, as explained in the other answer, but I would recommend you just use the nice and easy [remapping syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs//misc/Remap.htm#Remap) like this:

```
^;::z ; Undo
^q::x ; Cut
^j::c ; Copy
^k::v ; Paste
^x::+v ; Paste without formatting
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> triggers the "cut" hotkey, which presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, which triggers the "paste without formatting" hotkey, which presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

So the text processor receives

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (cut) and
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste without formatting),

which only clears the text formatting.

---

Fortunately, there is a simple fix: **the `$` hotkey prefix**. From the [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar):

> The $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to be used to implement this hotkey, which as a side-effect prevents the `Send` command from triggering it.

You just need to prefix the hotkeys that `Send` could trigger with `$`.

```
^;::Send ^z ; Undo
^q::Send ^x ; Cut
^j::Send ^c ; Copy
^k::Send ^v ; Paste
$^x::Send ^+v ; Paste without formatting
```